# Make div in navbar show inside responsive menu

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a WordPress theme from scratch using Bootstrap. I'm making the menu now, and so far it's going smooth. I have created a right aligned div for a top widget to show for example language flags. I have removed the collapse classes so the widget always is shown in the menu. The problem is that if you're on a smaller screen, I want to put the widget inside the menu, so the user have to click the menu button to see the menu and widget. Any suggestions?

Here's my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">TEST
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a>
            </div>


            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-left">
                          <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
                            'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav',
                            'depth'             => 2,
                            'container'         => 'div',
                            'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                            'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
                            'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                            'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                            'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker()
                            ) ); ?>
            </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-right">

        <div class="top-right">
        <div class="top-widget"> <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'right-top' ); ?> </div>
            </div>
    </div>

          </div>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use javascript to clone the widget and append it to your menu, then use CSS to show/hide it for the appropriate screen sizes.

Beware of the duplicate id `<nav id="navbar"`. Better make the right one `<nav id="navbar-right"`.

**Javacript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#navbar-right .top-widget')
     .clone()
     .appendTo( $('#navbar') )
     .attr('id', 'widget-within-navbar');
}):
```

**CSS:**

```
#widget-within-navbar{ display: block }
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #widget-within-navbar { display: none }
}
```

Disclaimer: It's been a while since I used the jQuery's *clone()* and *appendTo()* functions so I don't guarantee that my syntax is correct. But hopefully you get the gist.